# Heroku appears to be leaking memory after api-maintenance deploy - Enable allow-multiple-sni-endpoints feature

Tags: heroku

My Heroku App seems to be consuming more and more memory, so I think I may have a memory leak. It started happening at midnight, but I haven't made any changes in several days.
[image: memory usage]

The latest change was a change by heroku maintenance, so I'm wondering if that might be the cause?
[image: api maintenance change]

I plan to restart soon to prevent going over my limit.

Comment: might be worth trying a clean deploy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Heroku had several platform issues yesterday. There were several "platform initiated" dyno restarts and it seems like things are back to normal now.

[image]